# Displaying a user control on toolbar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created few simple shapes e.g. rectangle, circle shapes and able to place them on a toolbar so can be dragged/dropped onto Canvas. However, I'm having problem with showing of a WPF object which consists of 4 rectangles and lines. To make it easier I used blend 4 to create User Control and now have following XAML tags as User Control.

Question: How can I display this shape (combination of rectangle and lines) on existing toolbar?

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="test1.UserControl2"
x:Name="connector1"
d:DesignWidth="100" d:DesignHeight="90">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF1B1BCE" Margin="41.334,9.833,42.666,14.167" Stroke="Black"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF1B1BCE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33.334,29,0,30.5" Stroke="Black" Width="8"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF1B1BCE" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="8.833" Margin="0,9.833,36.499,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6.167"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF1B1BCE" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="8.833" Margin="0,0,36.499,14.167" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="6.167"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,29,24.749,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,34,24.749,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,39,24.749,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,44,24.749,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,0,24.749,40" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,0,24.749,35" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,0,24.749,30.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,0,24.749,25.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="17.917"/>
    <Path Data="M62.083333,37 L70.416667,37" Fill="#FFEFEFF8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Margin="0,24,24.749,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17.917"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how you can add your UserControl to a Toolbar.  Basically you need to add an **xmlns** declaration to the namespace in which you declared your control and then you can add it as a nested element in the ToolBar to make it a child item.

```
<Window x:Class="test1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <local:UserControl2 />
        </ToolBar>
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

To have something that makes sense you will most likely want to either add a border or add a mouse-over trigger to give some visual feedback.

Also keep in mind you have to code the drag-and-drop functionality yourself in the code-behind.

**EDIT:**

Here's how you would make a MouseOver border in your UserControl2 XAML file:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="mouseOverBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource mouseOverBorder}">
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. Of course, I can see a blank area now on the toolbar (blank square) with no borders so as you advised I tried  <local:UserControl2 Border="Black"  /> however, no borders are displayed in run-time since it doesn't apply to it in host level then I tried it in the XAML which creates the user control but same thing ....  any idea why it is empty and also cannot add the border to it?  I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: In a UserControl, the properties for the border are BorderThickness, and BorderBrush.  Writing Border="Black" shouldn't do anything..  If you are looking to add a MouseOver border I will append an example to my post.

Comment: In order for your UserControl to appear properly, you'll need to either manually set the size by setting the Width and Height in XAML, or in the code-behind for your UserControl you should override MeasureOverride and return the size you want it to be.  You are only setting the DesignWidth and DesignHeight, which doesn't affect runtime.

Comment: So far I have been able to add a border however, the major issue is that the shape (custom shape created in Blend) is not showing up. I'm getting an empty box with black borders on the toolbox.         I have included namespace as xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test1"> and then in XAML inside <Toolbox> tag I have <local:UserControl2 />

Comment: Anybody can give me some hints or a direction?